# Javascript: replace all in string issue

Tags: javascript, replace, replaceall

I can't figure out how to do a *replace all* in Javascript.

I'm in a particular situation because I have a *replacement map* like this:

```
  :)   ->  <img src="smile.png" title=":) ">
  :(   ->  <img src="sad.png" title=":(">
  >:(  ->  <img src="angry.png" title=">:(">
```

I'm currently looping on this map, and for each entry, i use `string.replace(from, to)`. The problem is that I cannot replace, for example, `>:(` because the `:(` is already replaced by the second entry. And if I reverse the map, then the `:(` in the `title` attribute will be replaced causing a real mess.

Hope you understood my situation. I need something like the PHP `str_replace` with array arguments, that do multiple replacement in one hit.

If it can help, I'm using Mootools.

Comment: Use a regex with global set in your replace! `mystring.replace(/something/g, '');`

Comment: Don't do this. Make sure your users can control how their input is treated, e.g. by using Markdown. You run the risk of mangling their input, especially if they're allowed HTML. If you really want to do this, then parse their input properly and only do the replacements on "regular" text.

Comment: @Cameron HTML is not allowed. User can type ONLY plain text. That plain text is then parsed on display-time replacing all smilies with an image version.

Comment: @lorenzo-s: Oh OK then. Never mind :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use analogue of php's `preg_replace_callback` with regex escaping.

```
var putSmiles = (function(){
  // init part
  var smilesMap = {
    ':)': "smile",
    ':(': "sad",
    '>:(': "angry"
  }
  if (!('escape' in RegExp)) {
    RegExp.escape = function(str) {
      return str.replace(/./g, function(m){
        // IE (at least 8) doesn't support .substr(-4), hence MOAR regexes!
        return "\\u" + ("0000" + m.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).match(/.{4}$/)[0];
      });
    }
  }
  var a = [];
  for (var s in smilesMap) a.push(RegExp.escape(s));
  // sort in such way, if b is substring of a, b should follow a.
  a.sort(function(a,b){ return -a.indexOf(b) }); 
  var re = new RegExp(a.join('|'), 'g');
  // actual function 
  return (function(text) {
    return text.replace(re, function(m){
      return '<img src="' + smilesMap[ m ] + '.png" title="' + m + '">';
    });
  })
})();
```

Comment: Why would you use `arguments[0]` instead of a named param?

Comment: +1, but `a.join()` should be `'(?:' + a.join(')|(?:') + ')'`, no?

Comment: @phrogz No reason. Named param could be used as well.

Comment: Depending on how the object is iterated you may create a regex with `:(` coming before `>:(`, resulting in failed matching.

Comment: @Phrogz Yes, they should be sorted in order to not interact.

Comment: @Cameron No reason to create groups for each match; alternation at the root level works fine without groups.

Comment: I had to do some reorderings in the map and solve some troubles with smilies containing HTML special characters, but it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Mmmm, in IE does not wark at all (no replacements at all). Can't figure out why.

Comment: @lorenzo-s It's the problem with my Regexp.escape. use `function(str){ return str.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|]/g, "\\$&"); }` from Phrogz's comment

Comment: @kirilloid I used the Mootools' **[escapeRegExp()](http://www.mootools.net/docs/core/Types/String#String:escapeRegExp)** and it's fine now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = {
  ":)"  : '<img src="smile.png" title=":)">',
  ":("  : '<img src="sad.png" title=":(">',
  ">:(" : '<img src="angry.png" title=">:(">',
};
str.replace( />:\(|:\(|:\)/g, function(found){
  return map[found];
});
```

By using a regex that matches all three at once you are guaranteed not to mis-hit on the alternative; using the function form of `replace` allows you to determine what the replacement string is dynamically.

**Edit**: to dynamically escape any 'special' characters in a literal string to be used in a regex:

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
  return text.replace(/[.?*^$()|{}\-\[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");
}
```

Comment: But how can I use my replacement map this way? If I run this regexpr for every smile, don't I face the same issue again?

Comment: Ok, but whis will not solve the problem I showed in my question. If I replace all `:(`, then I cannot correctly replace `>:(`.

Comment: The map I posted is an example. I have a bigger map with all king of characters.

Comment: @lorenzo-s That's fine: you just need to create a regex that joins them together with the greediest matches coming first in the alternation.

Comment: Ok, I can do it. But is there a way I can dinamically generate the pattern starting from my map (it's an array).

Comment: @lorenzo-s You would need some pretty serious string work to ensure that the regex is created with the alternation in the correct order. Yes, it's possible, but it's not trivial.

Comment: Nono, I was talking about a way to escape the smilies in order to create a regexpr concatenating them. Something that return `:\(` from `:(` (that is not safe in the regex).

Comment: @lorenzo-s Yes; the answer by kirilloid has one such function. Alternatively `RegExp.escape = function(text){ return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|]/g, "\\$&"); }`